# Bind view to viewmodel and show as dialog page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm working on cross platform library for Windows, Android and iOS.

And I have an interface method for showing complex dialog messages based on some ViewModel (with data and commands for binding) and corresponding view.

There is a Windows implementation:

```
// view and viewModel is valid at this point
public void Show<TViewModel>(TView view, TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : class
{
    var window = (Window)view;
    window.DataContext = viewModel;
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Can I do the same thing in Xamarin.Forms?

I found something similar:

```
var activity = Intent(this, typeof(DataPage));
activity.BindingContext = viewModel
this.StartActivity(m_activity);
```

But this is for Xamarin.Android which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to be using is the `INavigation` interface from the `Xamarin.Forms` assemblies. All views/pages provide it through a `Navigation` property and you want to be using the currently displayed one.

Once you have it you can then call `PushModalAsync` this expects a type of `Page` but I would expect you to be creating one if you want to show it.

**Bindings**

As for `Bindings` ultimately you need to assign your view model to your views `BindingContext` I have a base class for my Views that looks similar to the below:

```
public abstract class ViewBase : ContentPage
{
    protected ViewModelBase viewModel;

    internal ViewModelBase ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.viewModel != value)
            {
                this.viewModel = value;

                // Make sure we bind the view model to the UI.
                this.BindingContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Further ideas**

It might be well and above what this question is asking for however I have wrapped the showing of `Page`s like you requested in to the following implementation:

```
internal async Task<U> ShowAsync<T, U>(IDictionary<string, object> arguments = null, bool animated = true) where T : IDialogView where U : IDialogResult
{
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<U>();

    try
    {
        var page = (IDialogView)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        // Hook up event handlers so when either the Complete/Error is fired then we dismiss and pass the result back to the caller.
        page.ResultChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Hide the modal view.
            this.DismissAsync();

            // Do we need to perform a safety check when converting?
            completionSource.SetResult((U)e.Value);
        };

        // Pass in any arguments to the view.
        page.SetArguments(arguments);

        // Display the view and wait.
        await this.navigation.PushModalAsync((Page)page, animated);

        // Return the result of the view.
        return await completionSource.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogService.Error($"Unable to ShowAsync for view: {typeof(T).Name}", ex);
        completionSource.SetException(ex);
    }

    return default(U);
}

internal interface IDialogView
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs<IDialogResult>> ResultChanged;

    void SetArguments(IDictionary<string, object> arguments);
}

internal interface IDialogResult
{

}
```

While this does look to complicate the initial set up it means that you can simply call:

```
var result = await ShowAsync<MyView, MyViewResult>();
```

The big bonus is it allows you to show the new page and wait for anything that it needs to action and make use of the result of that action. Note it you don't need to handle a result from the showing of the dialog then it is possible to replace the U logic with a simple boolean.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give a brief example of how you could set up Bindings to your ViewModel

Comment: The [Adventures in Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinforms.wordpress.com/tag/mvvm/) site has a really good example of view-model-first navigation which also works well for dialogs etc, I've used it in quite a few projects myself. The main page seems partially down atm, so you may need to email the author or check wayback machine.